# Send UIImage POST to server from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am trying to send a UIImage take with the UIImagePickerController to a server POST along with other pertinent values. But I get at the line that tries to set the dictionary value @"image" to UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0):

```
-(void)sendImageToServer:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration] delegate:nil delegateQueue:queue];
    NSURL *uploadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...."];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSData *postData = [[NSData alloc] init];
    [postData setValue:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) forKey:@"image"];
    [postData setValue:@"1" forKey:@"categories[0]"];
    [postData setValue:@"4" forKey:@"categories[1]"];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                               fromData:postData
                                                      completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSError *err;
                    NSDictionary *JSONDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
                    NSLog(@"HTTP 200 response: %@", JSONDict);
                });
            } else {    
                NSLog(@"HTTP %ld status!", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
            }   
        } else {
            NSLog(@"HTTP post image error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

JSON serialization does not work here, because images are not valid JSON values. If on the other hand I try:

```
...
NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:postData];

    [archiver encodeObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) forKey:@"image"];
    [archiver encodeObject:@"1" forKey:@"categories[0]"];
    [archiver encodeObject:@"4" forKey:@"categories[1]"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];



    //NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
    //Now you can post the json data

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                               fromData:postData
                                                      completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {...
```

The key:value pairs archived do not seem to get to the server as such. This must be a routinely iOS coding task.

Even if I just try:

```
NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"image":@"123",@"categories[0]":@"1",@"categories[1]":@"4"} options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
```

The server does not get any keys at all...

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0); try this

Comment: you better ASIHTTPREQUEST or AFNETWORKING libs.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the proper usage of `NSData`. It's crashing right now because `NSData` does not have key named image (..or the other two after that). What you need to do is create an `NSDictionary` and then convert that to `NSData`.

Do something like this instead:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:image,@"image",@(1),@"categories[0]",@(4),@"categories[1]", nil];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary]; //Not currently using NSJSONSerialization since you want to post a Dictionary with an invalid NSJSONSerialization type in it.
//Now you can post the json data
```

Comment: Thanks @tdevoy. I had already tried something similar, but it throws and exception in the same spot: 
     [NSJSONSerialization datataWithJSONObject....]; I assumed a JPEG representation is not a valid JSON value: 
NSDictionary *dataDict = @{@"image": UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0), @"categories[0]": @"1", @"categories[1]": @"4"};
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];

Comment: Yeah, whoops forgot that NSJSONSerialization methods only work with NSString, NSNull, NSNumber, NSArray, and NSDictionary objects. You could use NSKeyedArchiver to convert to NSData instead.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with AFNetworking, it have a great way to make uploads, you can find the samples here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task

I personally recommend everyone to use it, since I started to use I didn't have any trouble to communicate my apps with webservers.

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking and the multi-part form post.  Here is a rough example (note I am passing in a block so your implementation will vary):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self POST:FullURLString parameters:Params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:fileName fileName:fileName mimeType:mimeType];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSData *responseData = [operation responseData];
        id retObj;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (responseData) {
            retObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
        }
        // Pass back the serialized object (either an NSArray of type NSDictionaries or an NSArray of type customClass)
        block(retObj);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed with error = [Error]: %@", error);
        block(nil);
}];
```